# Update query optimization with large data

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-optimization

I have products , and categories table, and a pivot table named product_catalog, I need to update the product_catalog table so that I can remove the categories which have less than five products. Those products which are in these redundant categories should move to their parent categories. I have written a query for this but problem is that this product_catalog table has 55213277 records in it and it takes lot of time to run .
Basically it is a nested query and we have to run this query for as many times unless there is no category left having less than five products. 
Here is my sql query I tested.

Can you propose me an optimized solution.

```
UPDATE product_catalogT AS C
       INNER JOIN
   (SELECT
       COUNT(*) AS tp, catalog_id cid, g.parent_id pid
   FROM
       product_catalog AS p
   LEFT JOIN catalog AS g ON p.catalog_id = g.id
   Where g.parent_id <> 0
   GROUP BY catalog_id
   HAVING tp < 5)
   AS A ON C.catalog_id = A.cid
SET
   C.catalog_id = A.pid
```

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN g... WHERE g = (or <>)` is the same as `INNER JOIN g`. Apart from that, although a little verbose, your query seems essentially fine. SHOW CREATE TABLE statements and the EXPLAIN for the inner SELECT would be useful.

Comment: How long does the subquery take to run by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little less writing, but for performance we'd need to see your tables, indexes, and the EXPLAIN, as mentioned.

```
 UPDATE product_catalogT C
  JOIN
     ( SELECT p.catalog_id
         FROM product_catalog p
        JOIN catalog g 
          ON p.catalog_id = g.id
        Where g.parent_id <> 0
       GROUP 
            BY catalog_id
       HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
     ) A 
    ON C.catalog_id = A.cid
   SET C.catalog_id = A.pid
```

Also, I might mention that this seems like a rather strange request

Comment: here is the explain data of the query

```
1 UPDATE C NULL ALL product_catalog_catalog_id_foreign NULL NULL NULL 2219 100.00 NULL
1 PRIMARY <derived2> NULL ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 8 bydepot_new.C.catalog_id 22393 100.00 NULL
2 DERIVED p NULL index product_catalog_catalog_id_foreign product_catalog_catalog_id_foreign 8 NULL 55213277 100.00 Using index
2 DERIVED g NULL eq_ref PRIMARY,parant PRIMARY 4 bydepot_new.p.catalog_id 1 90.00 Using where

```

Comment: So I need how can I make this fast and run with a quick response , Thanks,

Comment: Can you edit your question, to provide the extra information requested - the EXPLAIN  *and* the SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables

Comment: @Strawberry - Can't you remove the `g.parent_id` from the inner `SELECT`?

Comment: @shairoo - How often do you run this?  Is a user waiting for the results?  I am looking into doing it in the background and/or via something other than a multi-table `UPDATE`.

Comment: @RickJames Yup, seems so.